# Undefined reference to (g++ compilation with static library)

Tags: c++, g++, unix-ar

The project files is as this:

```
source
  parser
    parser.cpp
    parser.hpp
  brain
    brain.cpp
    brain.hpp
```

I first ran these two commands (pwd `source/brain/`):

```
g++ -c brain.cpp -o brain.o
ar rvs brain.a brain.o
```

I copied both `brain.a` and `brain.hpp` to `source/parser/`. Then I ran this command (pwd `source/parser`):

```
g++ parser.cpp brain.a -o parser
```

And I got this error:

```
/tmp/cceGRLZn.o: In function `main':
parser.cpp:(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `std::brain<long long>::brain()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `std::brain<long long>::init(int)'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `std::brain<long long>::work()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x2a4): undefined reference to `std::brain<long long>::clear()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x2ec): undefined reference to `std::brain<long long>::~brain()'
parser.cpp:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to `std::brain<long long>::~brain()'
/tmp/cceGRLZn.o: In function `int parser_extract_args<long long>(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, int, short&, std::brain<long long>&)':
parser.cpp:(.text._Z19parser_extract_argsIxEiRSsiRsRSt5brainIT_E[int parser_extract_args<long long>(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, int, short&, std::brain<long long>&)]+0x17b): undefined reference to `std::brain<long long>::push_back(long long)'
parser.cpp:(.text._Z19parser_extract_argsIxEiRSsiRsRSt5brainIT_E[int parser_extract_args<long long>(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, int, short&, std::brain<long long>&)]+0x37a): undefined reference to `std::brain<long long>::push_back(long long)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Source files:

```
brain.cpp [http://ideone.com/GNUxmH][1]
brain.hpp [http://ideone.com/M2IFAI][2]
parser.cpp [http://ideone.com/fJRzhD][3]
parser.hpp [http://ideone.com/mj6dST][4]
```

What should I do?

Comment: It seems you are using templates through header and source, You need to define those templates in header and include them.

Comment: Can you please show me how, this is the first time I use templates, or at least refer to a tutorial please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you implemented the member functions of your class template `brain` in the `.cpp` file. You need to provide template definitions in the header file so that the compiler can generate the appropriate code when it sees a template instantiation. So move the contents of `brain.cpp` up to `brain.h`.

As an example, consider these three files:

- `test.h`

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct test
  {
    void foo(T);
  };
  ```
- `test.cpp`

  ```
  #include "test.h"

  template <typename T>
  void test<T>::foo(T x)
  {
    // do something with x
  }
  ```
- `main.cpp`

  ```
  #include "test.h"

  int main()
  {
    test<int> t;
    t.foo(5);
  }
  ```

Each `.cpp` is compiled separately and then linked together. Imagine you are the compiler, and you're trying to compile `main.cpp`. You see that the code wants to use the `test` template instantiated with `T` as `int`. So now you need to generate the appropriate code for `test<int>::foo`, but to do that you need to have seen the function's definition. Unfortunately, you haven't seen it, so you can't compile this program.

Instead, the definition of `foo` should be moved into the header file to result in this two file program:

- `test.h`

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct test
  {
    void foo(T);
  };

  // Alternatively, you can define this up in the class definition
  void test<T>::foo(T x)
  {
    // do something with x
  }
  ```
- `main.cpp`

  ```
  #include "test.h"

  int main()
  {
    test<int> t;
    t.foo(5);
  }
  ```

Note that you should not be adding your own declarations to the `std` namespace:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 3):

First thing: **do not add any entity to the `std` namespace**. This gives your program *Undefined Behavior*.

From your message, it looks like you have added a class named `brain` to the `std` namespace. Remove `brain` from the `std` namespace and put it into some namespace of yours. The only thing you can add to the `std` namespace are *specializations* of templates which belong to the `std` namespace.

Secondly, *unless you provide explicit instantiations of the class templates you are using throughout your program*, **you should put the definitions of member functions of a class template in the same header file that contains their declaration**, to make sure that they are visible from the instantiation point.

Relegating them in a separate `.cpp` file makes it impossible for the compiler to produce code for the member functions that you are invoking from other translation units than the one which contains their definitions. [**This Q&A on StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) may also help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare an instance of the brain template class with the type you require, so in brain.cpp, at the end of the file, you should put:

```
template class brain <long long> ;
```

When you compile brain.cpp, unless you have template specifiers in there, it will not create any linkable code, because it can't instantiate the template class without a type declaration. That said, when using templated classes, it is better to keep them as pure header files